# How to use the Android emulator on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I click F5 ("Android Emulator") on VS2019 with a Xamarin.Forms app, I get a UAC popup for permission  dialog to give permission to "Microsoft" (I'm not using an admin account).

Then it shows me the option to create a new device. When I "Cancel" it shows me the list of devices, with one device that I had already created.

I click "Start" and it starts.

Meanwhile, Visual Studio is not debugging the app on it. And the "⯈ Android Emulator" button (aka F5) is enabled. Clicking it just repeats the above.

Comment: Is the output set to debug?

Comment: @NdubuisiJr Yes.

Comment: " give permission to "Microsoft" (I'm not using an admin account)" for which application AVD, emulator or VS? and try running VS on Admin mode

Comment: @Prateek Whatever emulator it is that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: But it tells for which application it is requesting for. `Program name`

Comment: @Prateek Yes. "Microsoft". Yes, that's strange. As for running as admin - I'm trying it now and instead of "android emulator" it said "pixel_2_pie..." and is working on it. Even though it's just a hello world app - it's taking a _long_ time to start debugging (the emulator appeared very quick). Anyway, so the only way to use it is to be running as admin?

Comment: @Prateek It's been a couple of minutes and it doesn't look like it's going to start debugging so I guess I'll give up and do what I did before - use a real device. Oh well, I tried...

Comment: I always run on admin to avoid these issues. there was an update in SDK recently, update Android SDKs , delete all emulators create new with latest SDKs and retry. it should work

Comment: @Prateek Thanks. Maybe I'll try that.